# tab group in angular 2 material does not show strip at the bottom

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>test website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Polyfills -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-login>
</body>

</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function(global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
            '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                meta: {
                    './*.js': {
                        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                    }
                }
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

I am using **angular 4.3.1** and **angular-material 2.0.0-beta.8** and **angular-cdk 2.0.0-beta.8**

app.module.ts

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

```
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    ....
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ....
    ....
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

xyz.html

```
<div class="q-payment-container">
    <md-tab-group>
        <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>

</div>
```

This is the output image [image: here]

In this image, it creates tabs, upon click it changes the tabs, but somehow, it does not show **purple strip** at the bottom of the tabs. Is there anything missing in the code?

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide  
I tried to include MdTabsModule in my app.module.ts file. But the output still does not show strip at the bottom of the tab

Answer (score 0):

You also need to import specific modules for Angular Material components. For example, for tabs you need to import `MdTabsModule` like this:

```
import { MdTabsModule } from '@angular/material';
```

You can find requirements for every Angular Material component in `api` tab, here it is: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api

[image]

Comment: I tried to include `MdTabsModule` in my app.module.ts file. But the output still does not show strip at the bottom of the tab

Comment: @MrugeshThaker, try to rerun the project. Didn't it help?